# How to efficiently handle incoming delayed events on a single timeline?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++20

I want to implement the algorithm that awaits for some events and handles them after some delay. Each event has it's own predefined delay. The handler may be executed in a separate thread. The issues with the CPU throttling, the host overload, etc. may be ignored - it's not intended to be a precise real-time system.

**Example.**

- At moment N arrives an event with delay 1 second. We want to handle it at moment N + 1 sec.
- At moment N + 0.5 sec arrives another event with delay 0.3 seconds. We want to handle it at moment N + 0.8 sec.

**Approaches.**

The only straightforward approach that comes to my mind is to use a loop with minimal possible delay inbetween iterations, like every 10 ms, and check if any event on our timeline should be handled now. But it's not a good idea since the delays may vary on scale from 10 ms to 10 minutes.

Another approach is to have a single thread that sleeps between events. But I can't figure out how to forcefully "wake" it when there is a new event that should be handled between now and the next scheduled wake up.

Also it's possible to use a thread per event and just sleep, but there may be thousands of simultanious events which effectively may lead to running out of threads.

The solution can be language-agnostic, but I prefer the C++ STD library solution.

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for boost::asio. I suppose you would have one input with async receive/read creating timers that fire after certain time. It all can be done in single thread

Comment: Coroutines (use boost version if not in c++ 20) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines

Comment: I should also point out that you will need to deal with back pressure (like node.js) or you will OOM if you can't handle all the events that are queued on a timer.

Comment: One last comment :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152393/c-non-blocking-async-timer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Another approach is to have a single thread that sleeps between events. But I can't figure out how to forcefully "wake" it when there is a new event that should be handled between now and the next scheduled wake up.

I suppose solution to these problems are, at least on *nix systems, [poll](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) or [epoll](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html) with some help of [timer](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html). It allows you to make the thread sleep until some given event. The given event may be something appearing on `stdin` or timer timeout. Since the question was about a general algorithm/idea of algorithm and the code would take a lot of space I am giving just **pseudocode**:

```
epoll = create_epoll();
timers = vector<timer>{};

while(true) {
    event = epoll.wait_for_event(timers);

    if (event.is_timer_timeout()) {
        t = timers.find_timed_out();
        t.handle_event();
        timers.erase(t);
    } else if (event.is_incoming_stdin_data()) {
        data = stdin.read();
        timers.push_back(create_timer(data));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two threads that share a priority queue.

**Arrivals thread**:  Wait for arrival. When event arrives calculate time for handler to run.  Add handler to queue with priority of handler time ( the top of the queue will be the next event that is to be handled

**Handler thread**:  Is now equal to time of handler at top of queue then run handler.  Sleep for clock resolution.

Note: check if your queue is thread safe.  If not, then you will have to use a mutex.

This looks simple, but there a lot of gotchas waiting for the inexperienced.  So, I would not recommend coding this from scratch.  It is better to use a library.  The classic is boost::asio.  However, this is beginning to show its age and has way more bells and whistles than are needed.  So, personally, I use something more lightweight and coded in C++17 - a non blocking event waiter class I coded that you can get from https://github.com/JamesBremner/await.  Notice the sample application using this class which does most of what you require https://github.com/JamesBremner/await/wiki/Event-Server