# C++ callback timer with start/stop functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, timer, callback

I need to create a class to replicate the functionality of a callback timer from a library I no longer have access to.

Basically, spawn an asynchronous thread that executes some function after a timeout is reached. However, if some condition is met before the timeout, the function is not executed, and the timer is cancelled.

I am not sure how to "stop" the timer based on some condition.

This is what I have so far (based on the answer to this post [C++ Non-blocking async timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41152393/c-non-blocking-async-timer) by [wally](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1460794/wally))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class Timer 
{
public:

   Timer(size_t time, const std::function<void(void)>& callback) : 
      time(std::chrono::milliseconds(time)),
      callback(callback) {}

   ~Timer() 
   { 
      if (started) 
      { 
         wait_thread.join(); 
         started = false; 
      } 
   }

   // TODO: Implement stop()
   void stop()
   {
      // ???
   }

   // TODO: Implement start()
   void start()
   {
      if (!started)
      {
         started = true;
         wait_thread = std::thread{ [this]() { wait_then_call(); } };
      }
      else
      {
         std::cout << "Thread " << wait_thread.get_id() << " already been started! " << std::endl;
      }
   }

private:

   void wait_then_call()
   {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
      std::cout << "Thread " << wait_thread.get_id() << " starting in " << time/1000 << " seconds" << std::endl;
      cv.wait_for(lck, time);

      callback();
   }

   std::mutex mtx;
   std::condition_variable cv{};
   std::chrono::milliseconds time;
   std::function <void(void)> callback;
   std::thread wait_thread;
   bool started = false;

};
```

Testing:

```
int main()
{
   auto f = []() {std::cout << "Executing Callback Function"; };

   Timer t1{ 3000, f };
   t1.start();

   Timer t2{ 10000, f };
   t2.start();

   // main thread is free to continue doing other things
}
```

Comment: The shown code uses `wait_for`. There's a `wait_for` overload that takes a third parameter, a predicate. Generally this "condition" would be defined in terms of a flag that gets set while holding the same lock that the thread is wait()ing on, so, with the suitable predicate `wait_for()` will terminate either when the timer expired or when the predicate is met, and an additional check will determine which is the case. Mission accomplished. Any C++ textbook on advanced multithreading will provide more complete technical details.

Comment: You're in for a fair amount of rewriting in order to get functionality that actually stops the timer. On the other hand if you set a flag in `stop` that's checked by `wait_then_call` to see if it should follow through and make the call, the job is fairy easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following meets all your requirements.

### Sample Code

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

template<class F>
class DelayedExecution {
public:
    DelayedExecution(std::chrono::milliseconds ms, F&& func)
        : ms_(ms)
        , func_(std::forward<F>(func)) {
    }

    ~DelayedExecution() {
        if (thread_.joinable())
            thread_.join();
    }

    void start() {
        thread_ = std::thread{ [this]() {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mutex_);
            cv_.wait_for(lck, ms_, [this]() { return stop_waiting_.load(); });
            if (not stop_waiting_)
                func_();
        }};
    }

    void stop() {
        stop_waiting_.store(true);
        cv_.notify_one();
    }

private:
    std::chrono::milliseconds ms_;
    F func_;
    std::thread thread_;
    std::condition_variable cv_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::atomic<bool> stop_waiting_{false};
};

using std::cout, std::endl;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    DelayedExecution task1(std::chrono::milliseconds{250}, []() { cout << "task1" << endl; });
    DelayedExecution task2(std::chrono::milliseconds{250}, []() { cout << "task2" << endl; });

    task1.start();
    task2.start();
    task1.stop();

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
task2
```

Comment: What if I need to start/stop the timer multiple times?

Comment: This is a code-only answer. Fortunately that's easily fixed by incorporating a reasonable amount, very little in this case, of explanation.

Comment: @DominicSesto Set stop_waiting_` to `false` at the beginning of `start` and you should be able to reuse to your heart's content... so long as you make sure the running thread has had time to acknowledge the condition variable and exit. That could be tricky to guarantee without more infrastructure.

Comment: @DominicSesto When you say start and stop the timer multiple times, should the timer reset each time it is stopped, or do you want it to continue with the same countdown? Resetting is a small change, but being able to toggle the countdown on and off requires some rethinking since nothing in the current solution tracks the time that is used up.

Comment: @DominicSesto Also, allowing the timer to start again after being stopped introduces a synchronization issue. Since `stop` is non-blocking it will return immediately and the client thread has no way to know when it is safe to restart the timer.  And, what if you call `stop` and the function is invoked before `stop` sets the flag? `stop` would need to return an indication of whether the function was invoked or not. And, if your restart the timer should it be invoked again possibly? This would need a much more detailed specification of how it should behave.

Comment: The timer would reset each time it is stopped

Comment: I think if the function is invoked and then `stop` is called during execution of the function, the function should just finish anyway.

Comment: @DominicSesto Note that this is all standard C++. Odds are really good that if you're targeting a particular OS or framework they'll have a tool that does the job better.